# What is the proper call for (void *buf)

Tags: c

I have a dll file to be called as shown below. I'd like to call it by passing my string.
MinGW compiles it without any warning, but running it I get "invalid user buffer" message.
I try to pass my string this way:

```
int i = wrb(void *buf, int len)
char subtext[] = "red";
void *buf;
buf = subtext;
i = wrb(buf, 3);
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: why don't you see documents or man/help for it.

Comment: Because it is undocumented.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's too small? Perhaps the called function requires zero-termination, which you're not getting due to the buffer being to small?

It's unclear how else the called function can verify the address, that's not in general possible.

You don't need to jump through the `buf` hoop, the array name `subtext` will automatically and correctly convert to `void *`, so just call:

```
char subtext[4] = "red";
int i = wrb(subtext, sizeof subtext);
```

Also note that magic constants (like `4`) should not be repeated, use `sizeof` when possible.

Comment: You are right about sizeof parameter, but the code above is an oversimpified version of real one, focusing on the problem. And no asciiz format is needed, the length variable insures that any binary buffer content can be sent. Th problem is the buffer addressing as error report states.